# kubectl get AzureAssignedIdentities -A -o yaml is empty

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-custom-resources, azure-identity, k8s-serviceaccount

I am trying to deploy an api version with the following templates:

```
"apiVersion": "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1",
"kind": "CustomResourceDefinition",
"metadata": {
  "name": "azureassignedidentities.aadpodidentity.k8s.io"
 },
"spec":{
  "conversion": {
   "strategy": None
  },
"group": "aadpodidentity.k8s.io",
"names": {
  "kind": "AzureAssignedIdentity",
  "listKind": "AzureAssignedIdentityList",
  "plural": "azureassignedidentities",
  "singular": "azureassignedidentity"
},
"preserveUnknownFields": true,
"scope": "Namespaced",
"versions":[
  "name": "v1",
  "served": true,
  "storage": true,
  ]
 },
 "status": {
   "acceptedNames":{
   "kind": ""
   "listKind": ""
   "plural": ""
   "singular": ""
     },
  "conditions": [],
  "storedVersions": []
  }
```

When I ran

```
kubectl get AzureAssignedIdentities -A -o yaml
```

I am getting empty response as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
items: []
kind: List
metadata:
 resourceVersion: ""
 selfLink: ""
```

Can anyone please tell what's wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it might be helpful if you can share the logs, to understand what is happening

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sai. The issue seems to be with AzurePodIdentityException, which again I need to fix. I will raise another question.